# R studio does not load correct working directory, so getwd() command does not work

Tags: r, rstudio

For a long time, I have noticed that R scripts sometimes open in R studio without the correct directory displayed. As a result, getwd() references the wrong path and much of the script doesn't work. It seems to occur whenever R studio is opened with a script that wasn't closed previously, and could usually be resolved by closing R studio and opening the script in R studio directly from File Explorer. Today, even that doesn't work, rendering the getwd() command useless.

I am running R Studio 1.3.959 on a Windows 10 PC with 64-bit R 4.0.2.

Comment: Do you have an example of the directory code launched and the error message?

Comment: You can use `setwd()` to change the working directory. Or use the `here` package.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your RStudio, and also making sure that your preferences are set (both in RStudio's Global Options/Workspace/General and in the regular R GUI) to **not** "restore .RData into workspace at start-up".

Comment: Thanks Gregor...I confirmed that RStudio was already fully up to date and setwd() is not useful because I shouldn't have to do this manually (getwd() would work if RStudio wasn't feeding R a misremembered directory). I unchecked the setting you suggested, and it is still a problem...whenever you open RStudio directly rather than opening the script file with RStudio, the directory is misremembered.

Comment: Thanks Yacine...sample code/message is below. Note that the path returned is not the path of the script from which the command is given. The same code works sometimes and not others based on a deficiency in what RStudio thinks the directory is.

> modelpath <- paste0(getwd(), "/FileName.txt")
> output <- func(data, modelpath)
 Error in modelCheck(modelpath) : 
  File C:/Users/pj2sc/Documents/FileName.txt does not exist